# AIDL ipc messaging caused nullpointerexception

Tags: android, service, ipc, aidl

I have a service that works in the background and receive messages every now and then . 
I would like apps to be able to connect to my service and receive those messages.
so what I did is implement IPC using AIDL. I have created two AIDL files :
"IExtMessage" :

```
package com.tfl.extprotocolservice;
import com.tfl.extprotocolservice.ICallBackMessage;



interface IExtMessage{
    void getMessage(ICallBackMessage cb);
}
```

and "ICallBackMessage" :

```
package com.tfl.extprotocolservice;

interface ICallBackMessage{
void onMessageReceived(int parameter,int state);
}
```

and created an app that would receive these messsages to test this IPC:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ServiceConnection{
    private IExtMessage binding=null;
    private parseParametersTask task=null;
    HashMap<Integer,List<String>> parameters;
    ParameterAlert alert;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        connectToService();
        task=new parseParametersTask();
        task.execute();
        parameters=ReadParams.params;





    }

    public void connectToService(){
        Intent implicit=new Intent(IExtMessage.class.getName());
        List<ResolveInfo> matches=getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(implicit, 0);
        if(matches.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot find a matching service!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (matches.size()>1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Found multiple matching services!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Found the Protocol Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent explicit=new Intent(implicit);
            ServiceInfo svcInfo=matches.get(0).serviceInfo;
            ComponentName cn=new ComponentName(svcInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, svcInfo.name);
            explicit.setComponent(cn);
            bindService(explicit, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);



        }
    }

    public void buttonClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.navigation) {
            DialogFragment dialog = new navigationChooserFragment();
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "navigation");
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.ptt){
            PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
            Intent i=pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.loudtalks");
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.d("SERVICE", "Service Connected");
        binding=IExtMessage.Stub.asInterface(service);
        try {
            binding.getMessage(cb);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.d("SERVICE","Service disconnected :(");
        binding=null;

    }

    ICallBackMessage.Stub cb=new ICallBackMessage.Stub() {

        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(int parameter,int state) throws RemoteException {
            Log.d("SERVICE","received parameter "+parameter);
            Log.d("SERVICE", "received state " + state);
            FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
            if(state==1){
                alert=new ParameterAlert();
                Bundle bundleParam=new Bundle();
                bundleParam.putInt("parameter",parameter);
                alert.setArguments(bundleParam);
                alert.show(ft,"alert");
            }else {
                if (alert.isVisible()) {
                    alert.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    class parseParametersTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ReadParams readParams =new ReadParams();
            try {
                readParams.setInputFile(getAssets().open("parameters.xls"));
                readParams.read();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

this is the relevant code from my service :

```
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return (new ExtMessageBinder());


}


    private static class ExtMessageBinder extends IExtMessage.Stub {
    @Override
    public void getMessage(ICallBackMessage cb) throws RemoteException {
        L.m("TESTSERVICE","getMessage in Service called");

        cb1 = cb;

    }

}
```

cb1 is a static ICallBackMessage variable that I save when a message is received.
and in my service , this is the listener that passes the messages :

```
        try {
            cb1.onMessageReceived(carParameter, state);
        } catch (RemoteException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            L.m("TESTSERVICE", "" + e1);
        }
```

so , problem is , sometimes everything works great but sometimes my service crashes with this exception :

```
05-11 13:55:28.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1924): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 13:55:28.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1924): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 13:55:28.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1924):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1333)
05-11 13:55:28.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1924):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
05-11 13:55:28.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1924):     at com.tfl.extprotocolservice.ICallBackMessage$Stub$Proxy.onMessageReceived(ICallBackMessage.java:83)
05-11 13:55:28.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1924):     at com.tfl.extprotocolservice.ExtProtocolService$1.handleMessage(ExtProtocolService.java:127)
05-11 13:55:28.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1924):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-11 13:55:28.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1924):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-11 13:55:28.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1924):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-11 13:55:28.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1924):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 13:55:28.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1924):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-11 13:55:28.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1924):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-11 13:55:28.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1924):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-11 13:55:28.763: E/AndroidRuntime(1924):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't know why it happens, maybe I have leaks somewhere or something. 
I have looked everywhere but couldn't find an answer .

Comment: what are you doing with cb1?

Comment: @pskink I save it to a static variable . and when a message is received I have a listener on that variable. 
I edited my question and added code to explain a little more

Comment: Have the same problem. Callbacks from a remote service. One callback works (it has a custom object) and the other one throws the exception (it also has a custom object). The stack trace is impossible to follow, the error is in the same place (the same two parcelReadExceptions()) and I have no idea how to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Your source code looks well. I'm not really know what's problem. You could try use oneway & out keyword. I write an simple demo [here](https://github.com/nguyentrungduy/Interprocess-With-AIDL/tree/Asynchronous_RPC/src), take a look if you want.

Comment: This should really be a comment.

Comment: I see, but I'm not really have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: Alright, if you can take some code from your demo and put it in your answer that is runnable, that would be preferable.  Link-only answers tend to be discouraged here.